# How can I block a website with Google Chrome without using an extension?

Tags: productivity

I cannot download extensions at my workplace.

Also it appears that Google Chrome no longer respects the blocks I put in the `/etc/hosts` file on my Macbook Pro.

I spent about 30 minutes searching Google and most sites were saying use an extension or they were out of date.

Does anyone know how to block websites in Google Chrome without extensions?

Comment: I know you said you tried it but the hosts file should work. Anyway I think this is more suited to superuser.

Comment: This belongs on [superuser](https://superuser.com) I think!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about navigating the workplace

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a work problem you can ask IT to update their firewall rules. Not sure how responsive they'd be on an individual's request to block sites for an individual machine, so best get your manager's backing first.

This will likely require you to justify spending IT time for this task, so you have to demonstrate value from blocking the sites.

So, best start with a support ticket and escalate to your manager as necessary. Maybe  you'll catch them in a good mood, who knows.

Alternatives:

1. [This post](https://superuser.com/a/723732) on Superuser: *Why is Chromium bypassing /etc/hosts and dnsmasq?*
2. use Firefox